# Android material animations in iOS Cocoa Touch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to do UI transitions similar to android material UI transitions in IOS Cocoa touch? Can core graphic or core animation do complex shape tweening like flash (not just animating simple properties such as opacity or size.

For example please have a look at the following link: https://dribbble.com/shots/1901531-Loading?list=searches&offset=1

How can such animation effects be accomplished in cocoa touch?